# Add tomcat virtual host without changing server.xml

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

Is there any other way to configuring virtual host in Tomcat without modifying the server.xml?

Currently I have configured the virtual host in server.xml, I am trying to minimize the changes in the tomcat files.

Answer (score 0):

Many properties of tomcat can be monitored and/or managed using managed beans or `mbeans`. Not sure if you can add virtual hosts, but you might have a look at the following documentation and give it a try. Either way this is expert stuff and is likely not for the faint of heart.

- https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/monitoring.html
- https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/funcspecs/fs-admin-apps.html

good luck